# ASP.NET - Response redirect to different folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, response.redirect

I am attempting to redirect a gridview on selection. However, I am getting stuck on redirection when the page I am trying to redirect to is in a different folder.

The gridview is in a folder named HR. I am trying to redirect this to a file called Staff within a folder called Staff (Staff\Staff). How can I redirect to a different folder?

```
    If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
        'Add to session variable; translate the index of clicked to Primary Key
        Session.Add("DetailsKey", GridView1.DataKeys(e.CommandArgument).Value.ToString)
        Response.Redirect("staff\staff.aspx")
    End If
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Response.Redirect("~/staff/staff.aspx")
```

Answer (score 7):

The main thing is to use `/` rather than `\`. You aren't redirecting to a folder on the server, but to a path on the website (the fact that this means a folder on your server is just an implementation detail).

You can do all the forms that you can with relative links. Hence `"staff/staff.aspx"` goes to the file called staff.aspx in the folder called staff that is in the current folder (assuming your folder-and-file based system). `"../staff/staff.aspx"` goes up a folder, then to staff then to staff.aspx. `"../../staff/staff.aspx"` goes up two first. `"/staff/staff.aspx"` goes to the root of the domain on (`http://mysite.com/staff/staff.aspx`, etc).

As well as all of these, `"~/staff/staff.aspx"` goes to the root of the application, then to staff within that, then to staff.aspx. This is useful if you work on the site such that this would be in `http://localhost/currentProject/staff/staff.aspx` because the project is at `http://localhost/currentProject/` but deployed to `http://mysite.com/staff/staff.aspx` as the site is at `http://mysite.com/`. This way the same code works both ways.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
Response.Redirect("~/staff/staff.aspx");
```